# Is the memory not reclaimed for Delphi apps running on Windows Server 2008 (sp1)?

Tags: delphi, memory, memory-leaks, windows-server-2008, critical-section

We have a D2007 application whose memory footprint grows steadily when running on Windows Server 2008 (x64, sp1).
It behaves normally on Windows Server 2003 (x32 or x64), XP, etc... where it goes up and down as expected.
We have tried with the included Memory Manager or the latest FastMM4 4.92 with the same results.

Has anyone tried to monitor the memory usage of any Delphi app on Win2008 and would confirm?
Or would have any clue?

Precisions:
- no memory leaks in the common sense (and yes I'm quite familiar with FastMM et al)
- memory usage was monitored with Process Explorer; both Virtual Memory (Private Bytes) and Physical Memory (WorkingSet Private) are growing on Win2008
- memory consumption was still growing even when there was memory pressure. (that's how we came to investigate as it caused a failure, but only on Win2008 boxes)

**Update**: the //** repaced **// code is much simpler than our app but shows the same behavior.
Creating a List of 10,000,000 objects then 10,000,000 interfaces, executed 2 times grows the used memory by ~60MB and roughly 300MB more for 100 more executions on Windows Server 2008, but just returns to where it was on XP.
If you launch multiple instances, the memory is not released to allow the other instances to run. Instead, the page file grows and the server crawls...

**Update 2**: see [QC report 73347](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=73347)
After further investigation, we have **tracked it down to Critical Sections** as shown in the code below.
Put that code into a simple VCL application with a Button. And monitor with Process Explorer:
it starts at ~2.6 MB and after 5 runs (clicks on the button) it stays at ~118.6MB.
116MB lost in 5 executions.

```
//***********************
const
  CS_NUMBER = 10000000;
type
  TCSArray = Array[1..CS_NUMBER] of TRTLCriticalSection;
  PCSArray = ^TCSArray;

procedure TestStatic;
var
  csArray: PCSArray;
  idx: Integer;
begin
  New(csArray);

  for idx := 1 to length(csArray^) do
    InitializeCriticalSection(csArray^[idx]);

  for idx := 1 to length(csArray^) do
      DeleteCriticalSection(csArray^[idx]);

  Dispose(csArray);
end;

procedure TestDynamic(const Number: Integer);
var
  csArray: array of TRTLCriticalSection;
  idx: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(csArray, Number);

  for idx := Low(csArray) to High(csArray) do
    InitializeCriticalSection(csArray[idx]);

  for idx := Low(csArray) to High(csArray) do
      DeleteCriticalSection(csArray[idx]);
end;

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  TestStatic;
  TestDynamic(CS_NUMBER);
end;
```

Comment: Are you referring to the Private Bytes, Virtual Size or the Working Set? Run Process Explorer from SysInternals to monitor the memory for a better idea of what is going on.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue, if you do not call TestMemoryInterfaces?

Comment: Well, I asked this, because you pass MyList.Add(TInterfaceList.Create()). 
The interface has zero reference count, when leaving constructor. So, there can be a place for "bad things" (sorry, I do not have Delphi at hand to verify this guess). I definitely saw a report on QC about this issue: user complains about possible hidden bug in similar code. The workaround is to use explict variable: I := TInterfaceList.Create(); MyList.Add(I);

Comment: Thanks all for the different ideas. See the new Update 2 and sam[ple code

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: you have to replace all calls to **`InitializeCriticalSection`** by calls to **`InitializeCriticalSectionEx`** and pass the **`CRITICAL_SECTION_NO_DEBUG_INFO`** flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Microsoft made a change to the Critical Sections to add some debug information. This debug memory is not released until the end of the application but somehow cached and reused which is why after a while it can plateau.

The solution if you want to create a lot of Critical Sections without feeling this memory penalty is to patch the VCL code to replace calls to **`InitializeCriticalSection`** by calls to **`InitializeCriticalSectionEx`** and pass it the flag **`CRITICAL_SECTION_NO_DEBUG_INFO`** to avoid the creation of the debug structure.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new sysinternals tool called [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) which visualizes the allocated memory. Maybe it could show you what the big memory blocks are.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include FastMM with full debug mode? Just include the FastMM4 unit directly in your project and set

```
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True
```

If there is nothing reported, maybe everything is normally freed on program exit (maybe because of reference counting). You could use [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/index.asp) to monitor memory in real time. With this application you can see the bytes "counting" for each class name and for rest of the used memory. Maybe you can see who uses the memory. The time limited demo version is enough for this job.

Comment: There is no leaks, it behaves normally EXCEPT with Windows Server 2008. So it must be between the MM and the OS.

Comment: When the Application doesn't leak then AQTime will not show raising numbers. I would try it, just to be sure its not your app.

Comment: How would you explain that the same code works with all Windows versions EXCEPT Server 2008? Would be funny if the OS could add memory leaks to your EXEs.

Comment: There might be subtile changes in API calls, which maybe look for formerly reserved fields in structures and interpret them differently. I found several problems when switching to a new version of windows (although I don't remember any memory leak).

Comment: That's what it is! They (Microsoft) changed the behavior for Critical Sections and it sucks!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the Private Bytes, Virtual Size or the Working Set? Run [Process Explorer from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to monitor the memory for a better idea of what is going on.

I don't have any specific experience with this (although I am running 2008 x64 SP1, so could test it) but I am going to suggest you create a test application that allocates a bunch of memory and then free it.  Run [Process Explorer from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to monitor the memory.

If you test application reproduces the same behavior then try creating some memory pressure by allocating memory in another process - so much that it will fail unless that previously freed memory in the first process is reclaimed.

If that continues to fail, then try a different memory manager.  Maybe it is FastMM that is doing it.

Comment: Did a test app. 
Did put pressure on memory.
Have to try with another memory manager... (sucks!)

Comment: So the test app had the same behavior?

Comment: Yes. Tracked down to a change in Microsoft implementation of Critical Sections. See update 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have [this issue](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=67690) (this is another issue, unrelated to the one, which I've mentioned in the comments to your question).

Answer (score 1):

I did this code to correct this problem on my applications.
Is the same case of FastCode, to make the fix run you must to put the unit as the first unit of your project.
Like the uRedirecionamentos in this case:
[image]

```
unit uCriticalSectionFix;
// By Rodrigo F. Rezino - rodrigofrezino@gmail.com

interface

uses
  Windows;

implementation

uses
  SyncObjs, SysUtils;

type
  InitializeCriticalSectionExProc = function(var lpCriticalSection: TRTLCriticalSection; dwSpinCount: DWORD; Flags: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

var
  IsNewerThenXP: Boolean;
  InitializeCriticalSectionEx: InitializeCriticalSectionExProc;

type
  PJump = ^TJump;
  TJump = packed record
    OpCode: Byte;
    Distance: Pointer;
  end;

  TCriticalSectionHack = class(TSynchroObject)
  protected
    FSection: TRTLCriticalSection;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

function GetMethodAddress(AStub: Pointer): Pointer;
const
  CALL_OPCODE = $E8;
begin
  if PBYTE(AStub)^ = CALL_OPCODE then
  begin
    Inc(Integer(AStub));
    Result := Pointer(Integer(AStub) + SizeOf(Pointer) + PInteger(AStub)^);
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure AddressPatch(const ASource, ADestination: Pointer);
const
  JMP_OPCODE = $E9;
  SIZE = SizeOf(TJump);
var
  NewJump: PJump;
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(ASource, SIZE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    NewJump := PJump(ASource);
    NewJump.OpCode := JMP_OPCODE;
    NewJump.Distance := Pointer(Integer(ADestination) - Integer(ASource) - 5);

    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, ASource, SizeOf(TJump));
    VirtualProtect(ASource, SIZE, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

procedure OldCriticalSectionMethod;
asm
  call TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

{ TCriticalSectionHack }

const
  CRITICAL_SECTION_NO_DEBUG_INFO = $01000000;
  NEW_THEN_XP = 6;

constructor TCriticalSectionHack.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  if IsNewerThenXP then
    InitializeCriticalSectionEx(FSection, 0, CRITICAL_SECTION_NO_DEBUG_INFO)
  else
    InitializeCriticalSection(FSection);
end;

procedure AdjustMethod;
var
  LKernel32: HModule;
begin
  if IsNewerThenXP then
  begin
    LKernel32 := LoadLibrary('kernel32.dll');
    @InitializeCriticalSectionEx := GetProcAddress(LKernel32, 'InitializeCriticalSectionEx');
  end;
end;

initialization
  AddressPatch(GetMethodAddress(@OldCriticalSectionMethod), @TCriticalSectionHack.Create);
  IsNewerThenXP := CheckWin32Version(NEW_THEN_XP, 0);
  AdjustMethod;


end.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alexander, usually this is called "heap fragmentation".

Note that FastMM is supposed to be more resilient and faster overall, but if the original app was tuned for the D7 memmanager, FastMM might actually perform worse.

Answer (score -1):

Well, memory usage can increase even if there is no memory leak in your application. In those cases there is possibility than you have leak of another resource. For example, if your code allocates, say, a bitmap and though it releases all objects, but manages to forget about finalizing some HBITMAP.

FastMM will tell you that you have no memory leak in your application, since you've freed all of your objects and data. But you still leaks other types of resources (in my example - GDI objects). Leaking other types of resources can affect your memory too.

I suggest you to try other tool, which checks not only memory leaks, but other types of leaks too. I think that AQTime is capable of doing that, but I'm not sure.

Another possible reason for this behaviour is memory fragmentation. Suppose you mave allocated 2000 objects of 1 Mb in size (let's forget for a minute about MM overheads and presence of another objects in user space). Now you have full 2 Gb of busy memory. Now, suppose that you free all even objects, so now you have "stripped" memory space, where 1 Mb busy and free blocks are mixed. Though you now do have 1 Gb of free memory, but you are not able to allocate a memory for any 2Mb-object, since the maximum size of free block is 1 Mb only (but you do have 1000 of such blocks ;) ).
If memory manager used blocks larger than 1 Mb for your objects, then it can not release memory blocks back to OS, when you've freed your even objects:

```
[ [busy] [free] [busy] [free] [busy] [free] ]
[ [busy] [free] [busy] [free] [busy] [free] ]...
```

Those large [...] blocks are half-busy, so MM can not give them to OS. If you'll ask for another block, which is > 1 Mb then MM will need to allocate yet another block from OS:

```
[ [busy] [free] [busy] [free] [busy] [free] ]
[ [busy] [free] [busy] [free] [busy] [free] ]...
[ [your-new-object] [free.................] ]
```

Note, that these are just examples of incresing memory usage, though you do not have memory leak. I do not say that you have the EXACT situation :D

Comment: How is that addressing that the same code works with all Windows versions EXCEPT Server 2008?

Comment: Why not? 
If code uses some sort of implementation details, which were changed in 2008/Vista, then why not? I mean your code and Delphi's MM.

Comment: This is not so much a problem of memory fragmentation, but of address-space fragmentation.

Comment: That's probably depends on how do you define "memory". I didn't say it is a physical memory, right?