# Delphi compatibility with Windows 2008 Server 64 bit

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, firebird

I have a plan to install my application which is compiled using RAD2010 in Vista 32 bit dev. environment, in a win 2008 server 64 bit.
I use Firebird 2.0 (32 bit) as database server.

Is there any issue? Or it should run without any problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem for this.

If you can use Firebird 2.1 (a version for 64bit server can be use).

Just take the fbclient.dll (32 bit version)

Comment: OK, I'll try to upgrade the Firebird Server first. I'll update the status here. Tq.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why it shouldn't work, 32 bit processes and services work well under x64. If you need lots of memory for you application you can set the LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag which gives your application access to 4GB of address space instead of 2 GB. If you want that you need to add a line containing `{$SetPEFlags $20}` to the .dpr file.

Comment: OK noted. I will give it a try. Tq.

Answer (score 2):

We have encountered 2 problems with Windows 2008 Server, but it does not seem they should impact you too much:

1. **Critical Sections** now come with a debug baggage that is cached and not freed when they are released. If you create lots of them, the memory footprint of your application will be much bigger. Can happen when using Interfaces or Threads heavily. see [is-the-memory-not-reclaimed-for-delphi-apps-running-on-windows-server-2008-sp1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780073/is-the-memory-not-reclaimed-for-delphi-apps-running-on-windows-server-2008-sp1) and [critical-sections-leaking-memory-on-vista-win2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804848/critical-sections-leaking-memory-on-vista-win2008).
2. When using **ADO**, there is a memory leak (in MS stack) when passing the **ConnectionString**. If you close the connections and open them a lot passing the ConnectionString you end up eating all the memory after a while.

Comment: I use the following code (using critical section) -> http://wishknew.multiply.com/journal/item/263/A_Very_Simple_Delphi_Logger

May it cause a problem in D2008 in term of memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is if your application is library that needs to be loaded into a 64bit Process.

Examples:
    Shell Extensions
    ISAPI applications